# Keep the same colour after page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, page-refresh

When I click the `div`, the `color` of the `span` changes to `red`, as i expected, but when I refresh my page the `color` isn't `red`, it returns back to original color, in my case `green`. How can I preserve the same color (red) after refreshing the page?
I event tried with `.apend()` but the situation is the same.

This is my HTML:

```
  <span>Green</span>
  <div id="changeColor"> </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#changeColor').click(function(){

$('span').css({"background-color":"red"});

});
```

Thank you all :D

Comment: You will have to use a cookie to store the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). You can use it (or a smilar plugin) to create / read and store information in cookies. Then when the page loads you can use this cookie to set the color of the `div` as it is stored in the cookie.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yrCrE/1/) JSFiddle.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to store the value in a cookie, test the value of the cookie when the page loads  and set the color of the div accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to save your information in a [Cookie](http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml). Other than that, or using some kind of database, there is no way to retain information after a page refresh.