# How to load chosen alternative css as default css?

Tags: javascript, css, web

I made a light and dark css for my web. Light css as default and dark css as alternative. It works perfectly with the help of JavaScript. Now the problem is, if a user select dark version and refresh the page or go to next page, it goes back to light css again. I need my web to load dark css as default css if a user select dark css. How will be it made? Is it with the help of JavaScript? If yes please give the codes too.

Thanks

Comment: 20 seconds of research is all it takes to find a solution for your question.

Comment: @Banana 2 days research couldn't find anything about this. If you could find it please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Investigate cookies.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421055/keep-the-changes-of-a-web-page-after-refresh) is one. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132502/keeping-js-changes-on-dom-after-refresh) is another one. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851413/how-to-keep-the-changes-made-to-dom-by-javascript-jquery-on-page-refresh) is a third one. and [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722910/keep-the-same-colour-after-page-refresh) is 4th one.

Comment: And another from CSS Tricks - [A webpage with alternate user-selectable stylesheets](https://css-tricks.com/examples/AlternateStyleSheets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save this information in browser cookies. 
Whenever, a user accesses the site, check in the cookies if he prefers the darker version. To set the cookie use :
    `document.cookie = "style=black; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";`

Then check the cookie when the site is loaded using this function:-     [credits : w3schools]                . .
    `function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
      return "";
     }`

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to change CSS via javascript (described like in [Replacing css file on the fly (and apply the new style to the page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844545/replacing-css-file-on-the-fly-and-apply-the-new-style-to-the-page)), it is 80% done.
Now you must save user selection of CSS somewhere, for example, using cookies.
If you use jquery.cookie.js, try to create cookie:

```
$.cookie('myvalue', 'here is value', { expires: 30 });
```

and to remove cookie:

```
$.removeCookie('myvalue', { path: '/' });
```

Hope, it'll help!